# How to calculate mean of two timestamp columns in R?

Tags: r, datetime, mean

I have data frame in R, where two columns are datetimes (POSIX class). I need to calculate mean datetime by each row.

Here's some reproducible example:

```
a <- c(
 "2018-10-11 15:22:17",
 "2018-10-10 16:30:37",
 "2018-10-10 16:52:46", 
 "2018-10-10 16:58:33", 
 "2018-10-10 16:32:24")

b <- c(
  "2018-10-11 15:25:12", 
  "2018-10-10 16:30:39", 
  "2018-10-10 16:55:14", 
  "2018-10-10 16:58:53", 
  "2018-10-10 16:32:27")

a <- strptime(a, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
b <- strptime(b, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

f <- data.frame(a, b)
```

The results should be like that:

```
                    a                   b           time_mean
1 2018-10-11 15:22:17 2018-10-11 15:25:12 2018-10-11 15:23:44
2 2018-10-10 16:30:37 2018-10-10 16:30:39 2018-10-10 16:30:38
3 2018-10-10 16:52:46 2018-10-10 16:55:14 2018-10-10 16:54:00
4 2018-10-10 16:58:33 2018-10-10 16:58:53 2018-10-10 16:58:43
5 2018-10-10 16:32:24 2018-10-10 16:32:27 2018-10-10 16:32:25
```

I tried following:

```
apply(f, 1, function(x) mean)
apply(f, 1, function(x) mean(c(x[1], x[2])))
```

Comment: Try with `Map(function(x, y) mean(c(x, y)), a, b)`

Comment: `f$time_mean <- f$a + (f$b - f$a)/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `apply` (which can convert it to a `matrix` and then strip off the `class` attributes), use `Map`

```
f$time_mean <- do.call(c, Map(function(x, y) mean(c(x, y)), a, b))
f$time_mean
#[1] "2018-10-11 15:23:44 EDT" "2018-10-10 16:30:38 EDT" "2018-10-10 16:54:00 EDT" "2018-10-10 16:58:43 EDT"
#[5] "2018-10-10 16:32:25 EDT"
```

Or as it is from `data.frame` `f`

```
do.call(c, Map(function(x, y) mean(c(x, y)), f$a, f$b))
```

---

Also, another option is converting to `numeric` class with `?xtfrm` (that also has `POSIXlt` method dispatch), do the `rowMeans` and convert to DateTime class as in @jay.sf's post

```
as.POSIXlt(rowMeans(sapply(f, xtfrm)), origin = "1970-01-01")
#[1] "2018-10-11 15:23:44 EDT" "2018-10-10 16:30:38 EDT" "2018-10-10 16:54:00 EDT" "2018-10-10 16:58:43 EDT"
#[5] "2018-10-10 16:32:25 EDT"
```

Comment: Nice to know this kindness of `Map`!

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate with the numerics.

```
f$time_mean <- as.POSIXct(sapply(seq(nrow(f)), function(x) 
  mean(as.numeric(f[x, ]))), origin="1970-01-01")
f
#                     a                   b           time_mean
# 1 2018-10-11 15:22:17 2018-10-11 15:25:12 2018-10-11 15:23:44
# 2 2018-10-10 16:30:37 2018-10-10 16:30:39 2018-10-10 16:30:38
# 3 2018-10-10 16:52:46 2018-10-10 16:55:14 2018-10-10 16:54:00
# 4 2018-10-10 16:58:33 2018-10-10 16:58:53 2018-10-10 16:58:43
# 5 2018-10-10 16:32:24 2018-10-10 16:32:27 2018-10-10 16:32:25
```